# ColdFusion inheritance of an array

Tags: inheritance, coldfusion

I know in ColdFusion inheritance works by using the "extends field" in `cfcomponent`. However I want to get the properties of a built in class, not one I already made. I get an error when I do something like this:

```
<cfcomponent name="dummyArray" extends="array">

<cffunction name="init">
    <cfparam name="this.firstName" default="John">  
    <cfreturn this>     
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="multiply">
    <cfargument name="num1">
    <cfargument name="num2">    
    <cfreturn num2*num1>        
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

> Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface array

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try the fully qualified path `coldfusion.runtime.Array` instead of just `array`. But you might want to explain why you even want to extend an array. A separate component, which has an array property/field seems more reasonable.

Comment: Well, this is mostly just trying to learn coldfusion. But I would like to add a standard deviation function within an array object. I know CF has libs to do that but I should be able to create a new object that inheriets functionality of an array + custom function I might find useful down the road.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? This is interesting because you are trying to treat a ColdFusion variable as a proper object.

Comment: Arrays are collections of values.  Putting a function in one seems like an attempt to complicate simple tasks.

Comment: @DanBracuk That's actually not uncommon. [C# supports extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), which are basically static functions hiding their reference to the class instance.